# How to search a public database in php or mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

I'm working on a music upload website but I want to prevent users from posting copyrighted material. Is there a way to connect to the copyright.gov database to then create some sort of search engine? I don't want to scan the actual audio files, I just want to do a simple name scan of some sort. I'm sorry if this is kind of vague, I'm pretty new to programming. Thank you for reading

Comment: No offense, but if you're new to programming you may just want to get something up and running before worrying about all the horrid details of IP laws. Even if you had access to an API that was spoof proof, someone would find a way around it

Answer (score 0):

No. [Searching government records for copyright information is a manual process](http://www.copyright.gov/forms/search_estimate.html), as the Library of Congress database is not fully digitized, and in any event only contains records for works which were registered with it in the US.